# Cerrar AlertDialog después de un Intent

Tags: android, alertdialog

Tengo una `AlertDialog` que no quiere cerrarse después de seleccionar una acción determinada, precisamente en el `setPositiveButton` al ir a la nueva `activity` al presionar **atrás** aun se esta mostrando.

**Mi Dialog**

```
           final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertaDeError2.setTitle("Bienvenido");
        alertaDeError2.setMessage("Es tu primera vez aquí. Te recomendamos ir a nuestra guía rápida");
        alertaDeError2.setNegativeButton("OMITIR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), false);
            }
        });
        alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("IR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertaDeError2.show();
                saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), false);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimerPaso.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
        alertaDeError2.create();
        alertaDeError2.show();
```

¿ Alguna idea ?

Comment: Buenas, tengo un canal de un amigo que explica como hacerlo si te interesa :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW_BQ-KNW0k

Comment: @ArmandoBarreda gracias por el video, agregando dialog.cancel(); o sin el el el dialog igualmente se cierra por lo menos en mi caso. mi error era la funcion show del boton positivo ..

Comment: Eso pasa cuando agregas `setCancelable(false);` a tu dialogo, pero como no lo agregaste entonces x default está en `false` ahora si lo cambiaras a `true` vas a tener que agregar el dismiss();

Comment: @marlonpya sii, entiendo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de realizar el `Intent` llama el método `cancel()` del `AlertDialog`:

```
    alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("IR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

          Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimerPaso.class);
          startActivity(myIntent);
          dialog.cancel(); //Cierra dialogo.

        }
    });
```

Comment: No funciona para el dismiss(); es mas lo marca en rojo ... bueno la solución ya la encontré era que  alertaDeError2.show(); no debe ir dentro del positiveButton ... por eso no lo cerraba al ir a la siguiente actividad

Comment: @AshleyBeeb Tienes razón, ya corregí, el método para un AlertDialog es cancel()! =| Debe ser de  la interface dialog, ya que es el que ejecuta el método onClick

Comment: Bueno alertaDeError2.show();   es para mostrarlo y lo estas realizando al dar clic al botón "IR".

Comment: Al borrar alertaDeError2.show(); ahora no tengo problemas el dialogo se cierra ... es donde estaba usando 2 veces alertaDeError2.show(); uno en el boton y otro en la instancia ...

Comment: en lugar de usar alertaDeError2.show(); dentro de onClick() usa dialog.cancel(); ya probaste?

Answer (score 2):

Tu puedes cerrar un dialogo con el método `dismiss()`. Eso cierra el dialogo y lo remueve de la pantalla. El método `show()` te devuelve un `AlertDialog`, que es subclase de `Dialog`, que tiene el método `dismiss()` para descartarlo.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    // declara un campo dialogo
    private Dialog alerta;
```

Cuando muestras el dialogo lo guardas en este variable:

```
    alerta = dialogoBuilder.show();
```

y donde quieres cerrar el dialogo simplemente usas

```
    alerta.dismiss();
```

Eso es para los casos en que realmente necesitas cerrar un dialogo por eventos fuera del flujo normal. Aparentemente en tu caso la razón fue otra y lo encontraste. :)

Comment: El dismiss no esta dentro de la clase AlertDialogo.builder tampoco el cancel() ya que he intentado esto

Comment: Ah, disculpa, te lo edito altiro.

Comment: lo curioso es que el boton negative funciona perfecto ..

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, el botón negativo llama a `dismiss()` por defecto, puede ser por eso.

Comment: Te reiras de mi, he descubierto el error jaja tampoco te diste cuenta en el Negative llamo a  alertaDeError2.show(); Jaja y eso no debe estar en ese lugar jaja

Comment: Es verdad. Por lo menos lo encontraste cuando (supongo) trataste de aplicar la "solución" ;). Pero implica que tuve razón con lo que recordé, en realidad **ambos** botones terminan con `dismiss()` por defecto, solamente que porfiadamente volviste a reabrirlo XD En realidad, me reí de mi mismo, creo que no voy a responder a más preguntas antes de pasar por un oculista.

Comment: si :( lo abri dos veces por eso el error :c no es necesidad de usar dissmiss()

Answer (score 0):

Estás en un error si usas el método `show()` para tu instancia de dialogo, éste método lo que hace es mostrar el dialogo por lo contrario deberías cambiar por `dismiss();` para ocultar el dialogo..

```
alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("IR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alertaDeError2.dismiss(); //<-- cambiar show() por dismiss()
                    saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), false);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimerPaso.class));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ya lo había comentado, quitado el Show y el dissmiss() al parecer viene por defecto despues de la una accion ya que ya me funciona bien.

Comment: Que raro lo normal sería q agregues el `dismiss()` dentro de un `setXXXButton` a tu dialogo.

Comment: yo pensaba lo mismo, pero al parecer no es asi ...

Comment: Eso pasa cuando agregas `setCancelable(false);` a tu dialogo, pero como no lo agregaste entonces x default está en `false` ahora si lo cambiaras a `true` vas a tener que agregar el `dismiss();`